# Lie bracket for a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying "An Introduction to Riemannian Geometry" by Godinho and Natário without a deeper differential geometry background so I might be a little confused with the notation.

The exercise 5 of the Section 1.6 is the following
[image]

I get that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is the basis for $T_pM$ but I find odd to do the calculations with these notation. Looking for the solution of (a)

[image]

Here the differentials are applied to $f$ but my efforts with this calculation are a bit clumsy. How can I apply $X_1$ and $X_2$ to the elements inside the parenthesis so to obtain $-X_3 f$ ? I would be very grateful with someone could provide a little bit of clarification.

Comment: Vector fields on a smooth manifold can be considered as derivation operators acting on smooth functions defined on this smooth manifold.

Comment: To expand on @Watheophy 's comment: Once you apply a vector field $X$ to $f$, it gives back another smooth function $X(f)$ on your manifold, so you can apply another vector field $Y$ to it to get $Y(X(f))$. The notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}=\partial_i$ is used because it tells you exactly how this vector fields acts. The expressions inside the parenthesis are just smooth functions, apply the vector fields using linearity and Leibniz's rule.

Comment: You will need to expand it out carefully and use the fact that mixed partial derivatives of a smooth function don't depend on the order.

Comment: Also, note that if $X,Y$ are vector fields, $XY$ or $YX$ may not be a vector field (i.e. they don't follow Leibniz's rule). But the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ is a vector field.